# Can a non-human legal entity own copyright?

Tags: copyright

Can non-human legal entities (for example, corporations) own copyright?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For example, corporations can own copyright.

They may own copyright after [assignment](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/canadian-intellectual-property-office/en/copyright/transfer-ownership) (this is true across much of the commonwealth and in the U.S.).

In some jurisdictions, [when a work is made for hire, the employer may be deemed the author and initial owner (e.g. U.S.) or just the initial owner (e.g. Canada).](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/87607/46948)